# `sklearn.preprocessing.normalize` (L2 norm) equivalent in Tensorflow or TFX

Tags: tensorflow

How can I do the L2 norm in Tensorflow? I'm looking for the equivalent of [`sklearn.preprocessing.normalize`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html) in Tensorflow or in `tfx`.

Comment: It's tf.math.l2_normalize()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tensorflow.keras.utils.normalize` for L2 norm as follows.

**Using `sklearn.preprocessing.normalize`**

```
X = [[ 1., -1.,  2.],
     [ 2.,  0.,  0.],
     [ 0.,  1., -1.]]

X_normalized = sklearn.preprocessing.normalize(X, norm='l2')
X_normalized
```

**Output:**

```
array([[ 0.40824829, -0.40824829,  0.81649658],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.70710678, -0.70710678]])
```

**Using `tf.keras.utils.normalize`** gives the same output as above

```
X = [[ 1., -1.,  2.],
     [ 2.,  0.,  0.],
     [ 0.,  1., -1.]]

tf.keras.utils.normalize(
    X, order=2
)
```

**Output:**

```
array([[ 0.40824829, -0.40824829,  0.81649658],
       [ 1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.70710678, -0.70710678]])
```